# Popup right under table row

Tags: angular, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a table and by clicking on a row of the table a popup window (simple div is displayed) should appear. Right now the popup is displayed under he table. How should be done the popup to be displayed right under that row which was clicked on using Angular and Bootstrap?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container =ngFor="...">
      <tr (click)="showPopUp()">
        ...
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
<app-popup-component>...</app-popup-component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the *ngFor directive into the tr HTML element like so :

```
<ng-container >
  <tr =ngFor="let row of rows" (click)="showPopUp()">
    ...
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Once this is done, you have might add the good css to the pop and it should be well displayed in each row